# Botbuilder Proactive cancelAllDialogs() with Node in Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure, dialog, botframework

I have a `logout` function in azure botbuilder v4 as follows:

```
async interrupt(innerDc) {
    if (innerDc.context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
        const text = innerDc.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();
        if (text === 'logout') {
            // The bot adapter encapsulates the authentication processes.
            const botAdapter = innerDc.context.adapter;
            await botAdapter.signOutUser(innerDc.context, this.connectionName);
            var logout = await signOut (console, innerDc.context);
            await innerDc.context.sendActivity('You have been logged out.');
            return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
        }
    }
}
```

I am however trying to replicate this within azure functions (for logging the user out proactively). I am trying the below code:

```
async function logoutUser(context, conversationReference) {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.adapter.signOutUser(turnContext, connectionName);
    });
    return true;
}
async function cancelDialogs(context, conversationReference) {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.adapter.cancelAllDialogs();
    });
    return true;
}

async function sendMessage(context, conversationReference) {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity('You have been logged out.');
    });
    return true;
}
```

The `logoutUser` and the `sendMessage` functions seems to work - but I cannot get the `cancelDialogs` function to work - I have tried the below as well as other such varieties:

```
async function cancelDialogs(context, conversationReference) {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async dialogContext => {
        await dialogContext.cancelAllDialogs();
    });
    return true;
}
```

I don't seem to be able to replicate the original `await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs` from the internal bot code, can someone highlight where I am going wrong please?